# What's a bash string manipulation substitution for this?

Tags: bash, scripting

I do the following in my scripts:

```
~/tmp$ cat quick.sh
#!/bin/bash
TEXT="Hello World"
KEY=$(echo ${TEXT} | sed -r "s/(^[^ \t]+).+/\1/")
echo ${TEXT}
echo ${KEY}
~/tmp$ ./quick.sh
Hello World
Hello
```

How can I extract the first word from a string just with tools BASH provides?

Comment: too much work to assign TEXT: `TEXT="Hello World"` -- no need to call echo

Comment: @glennjackman True, I just substituted the command I was using with echo.  Simplified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `${param%%word}` [Parameter Expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073)

```
$ var="Hello World" ; echo "${var%% *}"
Hello
```

Comment: Apparently, I've got to wait another 8 minutes to give you the check mark.  In the meantime, how would I do the opposite (remove the first word)?

Comment: `var="Hello World" ; echo "${var##* }"`. At least, see the documentation you are provided in the answer.

Comment: @AbhijeetRastogi I only 'saw' the answer.  You're absolutely right.

Comment: @AbhijeetRastogi Your answer gives the last word matched, I was wondering how to get everything but the first word matched.

Comment: `var="Foo Hello World" ; echo "${var#* }"` Again, from the link that was in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an array or the positional parameters as temporary placeholders

```
TEXT='Hello World'
tmp=($TEXT)         # must not quote the variable here
first=${tmp[0]}
second=${tmp[1]}
```

or

```
set -- $TEXT        # must not quote the variable here
first=$1
second=$2
```

Comment: I get what your saying ... perhaps you could break your code block into to two with "or the position a parameters as temporary place holders" seperating them to make it clearer. +1 for the `set -- $TEST`: that's a neat trick.